# JavaFX Controller method call from other class

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, controller, fxml

I am trying to get a JavaFX GUi combined with a Socket communication running.

So I got 4 Classes.

SocketClient: is handling the Data In-/Output. When the Client is connected to a Server a Label on the GUI should change.

```
private void openSocket() {
    try {
        client = new Socket();
        client.setReuseAddress(true);
        client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP,SOCKET_PORT),10);
        //Where do I get the Controller From?
        //guiController = loader.getController();
        //guiController.setLabel("Connected");
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

GUIController: this Controller should set the Text of the Label when the Client is connected.

```
public void setLabel(String status) {
    label.setText(status);
}
```

GUI: is loading the GUI (loading GUI.FXML....)

```
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
        VBox root = (VBox)loader.load();
        guiController = loader.getController();
        \\This is Working
        guiController.setLabel("test");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,root.getPrefWidth(),root.getPrefHeight());
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.setResizable(false);
        mainStage.show();
```

Main: is launching the GUi (GUI:launch(GUI.class)

So where and how do I use the Controller to set the Label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick strict to the Model-View-Controller concept, I would not do it the way you want to do it. The Model should not access the Controller/View directly. The Controller should call the Model.

[image]

[MVC Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

However, you can of course do it that way. Simply store the the `controller` variable you have when initiating the Controller/View and pass it from your MainApp to where ever you want it and call methods from there.

Comment: So then the Controller asks the Model (SocketClient) for new Data?

Comment: If you go strictly along the concept, yes. In theory, the model should be completly independant. The Controller is the level that manages what gets put onto the view. As I said, you will always find a way to "violate" that and it will sometimes be easier, but for a simple thing like this I would stick to the concept.

Comment: Can the Controller run as a Thread, because it needs to periodically ask if there is some Data on the Socket.

Comment: You could simply start a thread in your controller that asks the model for an update.